# how to block hotlinking for my media files?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, hotlinking

I have swf& images files that can be hotlinked from otherwebsites like in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657462/stop-my-swf-file-from-being-hotlinked) 
How can I use [HTTP Referer header](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_referrer) to have my swf files viewed only from my website ?

EDIT

My files are hosted at my server, I am not using Amazon S3 service, or other files hosting services.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if request.env['HTTP_REFERER'] =~ /yourdomain\.com\//
  # serve asset
end
```

Note that `nil =~ regex # => nil` so you don't need to check if `request.env['HTTP_REFERER']` exists first.

**Edit:**

More about the =~ operator: [Object#=~](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-3D-7E), 
[String#=~](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/String.html#method-i-3D-7E), [Regex#=~](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-3D-7E)

```
$ irb
> nil =~ /something/
=> nil
```

Comment: Can you please point me where to read about the nil =~ regex # => nil ? and the =~ operator ? I need to educate my self about them

Answer (score 1):

You should assure that referrer link has same domain as yours, like if you have nginx:

```
location ~* (\.swf)$ {
    valid_referers blocked mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    if ($invalid_referer) ) {
        return 444;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's nginx configuration files. This kind of job should be done not in application logic, apache/nginx will do it easier and much faster.

Comment: But, I am hosting my app on heroku, I don't know if this is possible